# Do We Want Hats™?

Tags: discussion

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the promotion to any site that wants to participate.

Here's the run down:

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available..
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by 28 November 2012, so vote away on if you want hats.

### **Please up-vote the answer you most associate with below to indicate preference**

## And the Ayes have it. We have agreed to participate as a site. (22 for/9 agin')

Comment: UM..........NO!  _I Hate Hats!_  But seriously why? what is the point?

Comment: @bluefeet The point I think is to generate more interest and activity on the site.

Comment: I'm with @bluefeet, unless we can get [this](http://www.hatsinthebelfry.com/images/stock_photos/indiana-jones-hat.jpg) added to the mix.

Comment: @swasheck There were dozens so it's not unlikely there was a Doctah Jones hat in there.

Comment: I personally don't care for the hats. Just one man's feeling.

Comment: @bluefeet The point is a little bit traffic, but mostly we wanted to do something fun and lighthearted at the end of the year. I thought lots of sites would like to participate, so I opened it up to everyone in the network. If this site chooses to opt out, that's totally ok (people can get hats elsewhere) but it could be a fun thing that gets people excited. :)

Comment: @Aarthi I have no issue with fun and lighthearted things...I am not really a grinch. :)

Comment: @bluefeet Oh! I'm so sorry if I seemed to imply that -- you'd asked the point/purpose and I wanted to be direct. Of *course* you're not a Grinch! This whole site is full of really fun, cool people, and you're *absolutely* one of them! :)

Comment: As long as there is a spam-hat, I'm in.

Comment: Presumably, feared pirate @Jco LeBrand prefers a bandanna to a hat.

Comment: And to respond to @Shog9 what I want is this: http://www.firestartoys.com/ProductImages/6763/BIG/BIG/BIG/6763.jpg ;-)

Comment: But I'm disappointed. No [pointy hats](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4231/gandalfz.jpg)? Or maybe I missed the entire collection? The site requires a pwd to enter, so can't see anything.

Comment: @Aarthi when when when?

Comment: @jcolebrand **19 December** it's even in the post!

Comment: Pffft: I meant, are you going to say anything else about this, or is there a blogpost, or anything? Specifically so when my users pester me about updates I can show them? (hence my pestering you)

Comment: I'm just curious what hat Jon Skeet's gravatar is gonna have on SO.. Maybe the Chuck Norris hat...?

Answer (score 24):

Bring on the hats.

## edit: jcolebrand:

Please no downvotes. We will ignore them. Unless it's just that cathartic for you.

Answer (score 6):

## Please don't.

One man's opinion anyway.  Unless they are tin-foil helmets for the DVs on this answer.

<s>This answer is provided for you to vote against the proposal (by voting it up) without hurting your rep.</s>

If it's going ahead anyway, can we pre-emptively have a "I hate hats" button to click *PRIOR* to the event so that we don't have to see it even once?

## edit: jcolebrand:

Please no downvotes. We will ignore them. Unless it's just that cathartic for you.

Comment: So what does the -1 mean? Is that a vote for "Please do"?

Comment: It means the vote gets ignored because _some people_ purposely want to see the world burn.

Comment: Did I miss something?  It seem like an up-vote here means I don't want to take the five seconds it will take to turn this feature off if it is enabled, but I will take five seconds to vote it down and ruin the fun for everyone else.

Comment: Also note that downvoting on meta doesn't carry rep repurcussions ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand Seems I learn something new after 20 months on so/se...

Comment: Keep in mind that it has cost on [metase] just not here

Comment: I would've thought that by voting + on my option and - on the other one my favorite would actually gain 2 points ;). But that only if all the others are just voting their option, not doing like me. PS: I voted only mine, but was really tempted to down vote the other :-).

Comment: @LeighRiffel I think am up vote here indicates that our site is too serious for this sort of frivolity ;)

Comment: @JackDouglas I suppose it depends how similar to badges the actions that earn hats are.  Badges promote positive activity.  If hats do this by being more prominent than a badge, then they are at least not entirely frivolous.  I do see your point though and that could explain the down votes.