# DBA.SE Xmas caption competition - 'tis the season to be jolly

Tags: discussion

**DBA.SE Christmas caption competition**

In the spirit of the festive season, [hats](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/so-whats-with-the-hats-thing) and all such matters, we proudly present the DBA.SE caption competition.

[image]

The rules are simple: Answer this meta question.  Edit the image above in a photo editor of your choice and add a caption.  The caption must be on a database related topic.

Other users can then vote on your answer and the answer with the most upvotes wins.  The competition closes on December 31 and the mods will get in touch with the winner to arrange delivery.  Downvotes, of course, don't count.

First prize is a [240GB Intel 330 SSD](http://ark.intel.com/products/70274/Intel-SSD-330-Series-240GB-SATA-6Gbs-25nm-MLC) so it's not small change.  Consolation prizes will be awarded on completely arbitrary grounds.

Time to get creative, and may the best caption win.

**EDIT:** and we have a [winner.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/873/2092)

Comment: <mumble>stupid .. you got a <grumble>HAT off of <blah>post...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: Hibernate]

Comment: And we have a winner ... as at Midnight 1 Jan 2013 UTC (measured as accurately as the clock on my laptop is set, which is in no way synchronised to any atomic clocks at all).

Comment: I'd like to thank all of the Java developers that I've worked with for this accolade!

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Comment: Done! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 11):

[image: 20000 databases]

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: Always wondered what Bob looked like... lol

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: Might be better putting the text at the bottom.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells canvas expanded...

Comment: What I meant is that the text really shouldn't be right over the face - just graphic design 101.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. It took me a while, but very funny (and true)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 3):

Enjoy my skills of an artist

[image]

Comment: Downvotes don't count btw.

Comment: Related [aliens meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ancient-aliens)

Comment: [Give us some deets for some swag!](http://j.mp/DBACaptionContest2012)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nothin' but love for you, @AaronBertrand!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> ...add ***a caption***. The caption must be **on** a ***database related topic***.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> ...and may the **best** caption win.

[image]

```
UPDATE Entries SET Winner='Y' WHERE Caption = 'best';
```