# Image choice for caption competitions

Tags: discussion

I recently deleted a competition initiated by a user on this site.  I have extremely mixed feelings since:

1. We love when users show initiative on our sites.  In this case, there was a major award and it a continuation of a successful contest the [previous year](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/dba-se-xmas-caption-competition-tis-the-season-to-be-jolly).  That's awesome!
2. However, the image chosen this year was not the best choice.  I don't think the photo was chosen maliciously.  As a standalone, there's nothing particularly offensive; it's clearly a stunt from the early days of robotics.  But in the context of a caption contest, it lends itself to innuendo that we don't really want this site to be associated with.  The early submissions have already veered off into creepy territory.

We hate to be grinches, but I'm shutting the contest down until a more appropriate image is found.

---

As an aside, diversity in the technology industry is something [Stack Exchange tries to encourage](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/11/podcast-54-the-one-with-all-the-anachronisms/).  In a male-dominated industry, we need make our workplaces more comfortable for women.  My previous employer encouraged women to cross-train as DBAs, for instance.  I'd be curious to know how your workplace has handled the issue.

Comment: The image was a life magazine cover from about 1960.  I had assumed that people would appreciate the irony.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells: Sorry to be a curmudgeon on this.  I must say that part of my problem with the image was that when I searched for it...  well, it didn't end well.  Thanks to your comment I've tracked down the machine as [MOBOT Mark II](http://cyberneticzoo.com/?p=4705).  It's pretty cool looking in a concept car sort of way.  At any rate, it's impossible to predict how things will turn out before you try. ;-)

Comment: [My caption to the image was a quote from the very same time period.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708446/quotes?qt=qt0550681) I am truly sorry if I have offended anyone with it.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - I'm not sure anyone was offended (although maybe someone complained).  I think the powers that be are probably just being image conscious.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: No worries.  Context is everything, isn't it?

Comment: @JonEricson - We've got an obvious favourite for the caption competition.  I've edited the question; can you please undelete it and post a message to that effect on the heap?

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells I could undelete it, but I think the best bet is to just repost it, do you mind doing that?

Comment: So what happened to our winter competition? Still having it?

Answer (score 9):

Official entry.

[image]

Comment: This might work, but without the captions. Otherwise there's no contest.. ;).

Comment: Has someone got a copy of this photo sans speech bubbles?

Comment: @Concerned http://www.sqlperformance.com/app/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/PASS-Us2.jpg

Answer (score 6):

So, shall we use this post to suggest an alternative image?

If so, here's mine:

[image]

:)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this one at a local bookstore:

[image]

I, uhhh .. didn't open the book, but someone could shop doge over the digital world and it'd be so big, much data, captioned.

Answer (score 2):

Big data in reality

[image]